# Не двигается input

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, html-form

Почему с помощью свойства margin-top: -Xpx не получается передвинуть поле ввода в вверх?

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text" class="find">
    <img src="img/audio.png" alt="" class="audio">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k5txhzen/

Comment: В примере по ссылке, некуда двигать input, если добавить еще один, то он перекрывает предыдущий - значит все работает.

Comment: margin это наружные отступы , если надо сдвинуть куда то  то применяйте - position или translate , примерно так : https://jsfiddle.net/k5txhzen/4/

Comment: .find{display: table;} - это свойство добавьте в класс и будет двигаться.